# Можно ли каким-то образом оптимизировать вот такой парсинг XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Два класса для запоминания разобранного:

```
class Answer
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public bool Correct { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
    }

    class Question
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string MainQuestion { get; set; }
        public int MainQuestionContent { get; set; }
        public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; } = new List<Answer>();
    }
```

Далее сам XML и его парсинг:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
                 <testing>
                  <questions>
                    <question id=""1"" content=""hi"">
                      <main_question content=""1"">Вопрос 1</main_question>
                      <answer index=""1"" correct=""true"">Ответ 1</answer>
                      <answer index=""2"" correct=""true"">Ответ 2</answer>
                      <answer index=""3"" correct=""false"">Ответ 3</answer>
                    </question>
                  </questions>
                </testing>";

        XElement elements = XElement.Parse(xml);

        List<Question> questionsList = new List<Question>();
        Question itemQuestion;
        Answer itemAnswer;

        foreach (XElement question in elements.Element("questions").Elements("question"))
        {
            itemQuestion = new Question();

            itemQuestion.Id = Convert.ToInt32(question.Attribute("id")?.Value);
            itemQuestion.Content = question.Attribute("content")?.Value;
            itemQuestion.MainQuestion = question.Element("main_question")?.Value;
            itemQuestion.MainQuestionContent = Convert.ToInt32(question.Element("main_question")?.Attribute("content")?.Value);

            var answers = from a in question.Elements("answer")
                          select new
                          {
                              AttributeIndex = a.Attribute("index")?.Value,
                              AttributeCorrect = a.Attribute("correct")?.Value,
                              Answer = a?.Value
                          };

            if (answers.Any())
            {
                foreach (var item in answers)
                {
                    itemAnswer = new Answer();

                    itemAnswer.Index = Convert.ToInt32(item.AttributeIndex);
                    itemAnswer.Correct = Convert.ToBoolean(item.AttributeCorrect);
                    itemAnswer.Desc = item.Answer;

                    itemQuestion.Answers.Add(itemAnswer);
                }
            }

            questionsList.Add(itemQuestion);

        }
    }
```

Хотелось бы `foreach (XElement question in elements.Element("questions").Elements("question"))`
 превратить в запрос LINQ, только я не могу сообразить как.

Благодаря подсказке @Grundy получилось оптимизировать так:

```
List<Question> questionsList = (from question in elements.Element("questions").Elements("question")
                                        select new Question()
                                        {
                                            Id = Convert.ToInt32(question.Attribute("id")?.Value),
                                            Content = question.Attribute("content")?.Value,
                                            MainQuestion = question.Element("main_question")?.Value,
                                            MainQuestionContent = Convert.ToInt32(question.Element("main_question")?.Attribute("content")?.Value),
                                            Answers = (from a in question.Elements("answer")
                                                       select new Answer
                                                       {
                                                           Index = Convert.ToInt32(a.Attribute("index")?.Value),
                                                           Correct = Convert.ToBoolean(a.Attribute("correct")?.Value),
                                                           Desc = a?.Value

                                                       }).ToList()
                                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Странно, точно такая же XML была тут от другого пользователя и он спрашивал, как в принципе её парсить, а потом удалил вопрос)

Comment: @YuryBakharev Да, а я озадачился и пока писал, он удалил вопрос...

Comment: если вам нужно прегнать XML в объект, тем более не слишком сложный, можно разметить целевой класс атрибутами сериализации и просто десериализовать XML в коллекцию объектов, в 2-3 строки. Это будет немного быстрее.

Comment: @rdorn, спасибо за идею, но в том то и дело, что я столкнулся с разбором муторно сложно-вложенного xml, который отдает API словаря Marriam-Webster, а этот конкретный пример был изначально не мой, а другого пользователя. Я лишь потренировался "на кошечках".

Comment: ну если это XML от API, то наверняка к нему есть схема XSD для проверки, а при наличии схемы можно воспользоваться тулзой для генерации классов по схеме, включая методы сериализации. Но правда тулза которой я пользовался, требовала нормальную схему, для нормальной генерации классов. Тут уж какой вариант ближе. Вот эту штуку юзал https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/

Comment: @rdorn в том то и дело, что бесплатникам схему не дают, а только файл ворд с таблицей возможных тегов и атрубитов. Я пробовал сгенерить классы через VS и через xml2csharp, но дело в том, что в зависимости от запрошенного слова, приходит разный ответ, с разным набором тегов, вообщем только вручную, только хардкор.

Comment: ну если есть описание, то схему составить не так уж сложно, впрочем не важно какой путь выбрать, главное чтобы к решению вывел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По сути, код эквивалентен обычному `select`

Например такому:

```
List<Question> questionsList = (from question in elements.Element("questions").Elements("question")
                                select new Question(){
                                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(question.Attribute("id")?.Value),
                                    ...
                                    Answers = (from a in question.Elements("answer")
                                               select new Answer
                                               {
                                                   Index = Convert.ToInt32(a.Attribute("index")?.Value),
                                                   ...
                                               }).ToList()
                                }).ToList();
```

Comment: А как мне в этот запрос впихнуть if (answers.Any()) и foreach(по анонимным answers)?

Comment: @Bulson, этот if ненужен. - приведенный код возвращает то же, что и код в вопросе